# Thoughts on securing SWFUpload

Tags: php, security, swfupload

One of the issues with using a Flash uploader controlled by Javascript (e.g. SWFUpload) is that Flash starts its own session when executing the upload script. This means that if the upload script authenticates the user, it will fail.

One way around this is to pass a PHPSESSID as a post parameter to the script. This isn't a perfect solution, however, since many hosting providers have the PHP setting "session_use_only_cookies" turned on, preventing session IDs from being accepted from the request.

It's obviously a major concern at times that you don't want anonymous users executing your upload script, passing it god-knows-what from god-knows-where.

I'm wondering if anyone has any alternative ideas for authenticating users other than sessions and cookies. Would it be possible to validate that the Flash request came from the expected source and that a valid user initiated the request. Using some kind of token other than PHPSESSID, perhaps, how could this work, if at all?

Comment: `many hosting providers have the PHP setting "session_use_only_cookies" turned on` you kidding. show me at least one

Comment: I think it's forced problem. you refuse to use optimal solution under very clumsy excuse, and looking for some weird ones. there is no problem with passing session id at least manually, using session_id() function. Hope it isn't disabled in your imaginable hosting providers

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to validate that the Flash request came from the expected source and that a valid user initiated the request.

[Not reliably, no](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem). You can never reliably validate that the Flash request came from "the expected source". You can only validate its contents.

> Using some kind of token other than PHPSESSID, perhaps, how could this work, if at all?

You could invent your own "session resumption token" (a.k.a. "remember me cookie") functionality to associate an SWFUpload session with a PHP session. But it wouldn't authenticate the client software, just the relationship between the two sessions.